# JSON-LD Structured data headings

Tags: structured-data, json-ld

I have a question regarding structured data (JSON-LD) for SEO.

What I would like to know if it is possible to add H1, H2, H3 tags in my JSON-LD code in my page header.

Example :

```
H1 : My wonderful website
My wonderful website, bla bla

H2 : Where is my wonderful website about?
My wonderful website is about birds and bees

H3 : Why watching my wonderful website?
Because it's great!
```

Now is there a way to add this in a structured data feed?

So is there anything like :

```
    {
        "@type": "heading",
        "@id": "https://www.example.com/#mywonderfulwebsite",
        "name": "h1",
        "text": "My wonderful website",
        "description": "My wonderful website, bla..."
    },
    {
        "@type": "heading",
        "@id": "https://www.example.com/#whereismywonderfulwebsiteabout",
        "name": "h2",
        "text": "Where is my wonderful website about?",
        "description": "My wonderful website is about..."
    },
    {
        "@type": "heading",
        "@id": "https://www.example.com/#whywatchingmywonderfulwebsite",
        "name": "h3",
        "text": "Why watching my wonderful website?",
        "description": "Because it's great!..."
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

Aside from generating [rich snippets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/rich-snippets/info), we use structured data for semantics - to convey meaning about our content.

`<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, and so forth are *inherently* semantic. So there is no need to do anything extra here. By using them in a hierarchal structure on your webpages, the meaning that you are conveying is what the page is overall about, the primary topics, the sub topics, etc.